# Google Search : Why does redirect kill performance

Tags: redirects, google-search

According to Ilya Grigorik who works on Google Search Engine , redirects kill performance especially on mobile , I dont understand why ??

Comment: Source - https://plus.google.com/+IlyaGrigorik/posts/aiXNxbdHfuc

Answer (score 2):

Because of the nature how redirects work, there are 2 requests made during a redirect.

The example will use redirected CSS file (from `example.com/content.css` to `example.net/some/folder/content.css`), but it works same way for all redirected content:

1. The initial request to fetch `example.com/content.css`.
2. The response for this request will be that it is redirected to `example.net/some/folder/content.css`.
3. The browser will fire another request to `example.net/some/folder/content.css`.
4. The browser will receive `content.css`.

Now, without redirection, this process would only need 1 request to process:

1. The initial request to fetch `example.com/content.css`.
2. The browser will receive `content.css`.

As there might be many resources redirected on a single web-page, you can see how that will impact performance as it needs to make two requests instead of one every time. Using `Permanent Redirects` helps here for clients as browser caches the redirection and should issue requests to redirected content straight away. This will not be the case for Google Crawler I assume, as it should really check raw (non-cached) requests every time too track changes in the redirects.

Comment: If you redirect to a different domain you also have the overhead of another DNS lookup.